# Header and footer Dynamically Changing but we are passing the Static URL access from GWT

Tags: java, vs-web-application-project

We are maintaining the Static URL in the xml file the same is getting reading in the java filter file.
URL hit may vary from Locale but currently I want for India location.

*I am keep on reloading the same Page but header and Footer URL is getting changed as some other countries URL. Not able to understand how its getting changed.*

**Below is the code for the filtering from xml file,**

```
try{
Map<String, String> configData = null;
            configData = EcomConfigService.getConfigurationDataForLocale(
                    httpReq, locale);
    // Here Locale will be loaded Example: INDIA as the country
            String proxy = "";
            String port = "";
            String gwtShfFlag = "";
            int shfTimeOutValue;
            if (configData != null) {
                proxy = configData.get("proxy");
                port = configData.get("port");
                gwtShfFlag = configData.get("gwtShfFlag");
                //Setted the gwtShfFlag as "TRUE"
                shfTimeOutValue = Integer.parseInt(configData.get("shf_timeout"));
                logger.info("gwtShfFlag:: " + gwtShfFlag);
                logger.info("SHF Timeout Value in Milliseconds:: " + shfTimeOutValue);
                if(gwtShfFlag != null && gwtShfFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                    HEADER_URL=configData.get("gwt_shared_header");//Loading the Header URL
                    FOOTER_URL=configData.get("gwt_shared_footer"); //Loading the Footer URL
                    HEADER_RESPONSIVE_URL=configData.get("gwt_shared_responsive_header"); //Static Header URL from GWT for INDIA 
                    FOOTER_RESPONSIVE_URL=configData.get("gwt_shared_responsive_footer"); //Static Footer URL from GWT for INDIA 
                    Proxy proxyTemp = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
                        proxy, Integer.parseInt(port)));
                // Open connection and get response for Header.
                URL urlH = new URL(HEADER_URL);
                URLConnection conH = urlH.openConnection(proxyTemp);
                conH.setConnectTimeout(shfTimeOutValue);
                conH.setReadTimeout(shfTimeOutValue);
                InputStream isH = conH.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader brH = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isH));
                StringBuilder sbH = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLineH = brH.readLine()) != null) {
                        sbH.append(inputLineH);
                    }

                // Open connection and get response for Footer.
                URL urlF = new URL(FOOTER_URL);
                URLConnection conF = urlF.openConnection(proxyTemp);
                conF.setConnectTimeout(shfTimeOutValue);
                conF.setReadTimeout(shfTimeOutValue);
                InputStream isF = conF.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader brF = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isF));
                StringBuilder sbF = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLineF = brF.readLine()) != null) {
                        sbF.append(inputLineF);
                    }

                URL urlRH = new URL(HEADER_RESPONSIVE_URL);
                URLConnection conRH = urlRH.openConnection(proxyTemp);
                conRH.setConnectTimeout(shfTimeOutValue);
                conRH.setReadTimeout(shfTimeOutValue);
                InputStream isRH = conRH.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader brRH = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isRH));
                StringBuilder sbRH = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLineRH = brRH.readLine()) != null) {
                        sbRH.append(inputLineRH);
                    }

                URL urlRF = new URL(FOOTER_RESPONSIVE_URL);
                URLConnection conRF = urlRF.openConnection(proxyTemp);
                conRF.setConnectTimeout(shfTimeOutValue);
                conRF.setReadTimeout(shfTimeOutValue);
                InputStream isRF = conRF.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader brRF = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isRF));
                StringBuilder sbRF = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLineRF = brRF.readLine()) != null) {
                        sbRF.append(inputLineRF);
                    }

                // Set header and footer response in request scope.
                httpReq.setAttribute("inputLineH", sbH.toString());
                httpReq.setAttribute("inputLineF", sbF.toString());
                httpReq.setAttribute("inputLineRH", sbRH.toString());
                httpReq.setAttribute("inputLineRF", sbRF.toString());
                Locales locales = localeList;
                    if (locales != null) {
                        for (Locale local : locales.getLocale()) {
                            String localeId = local.getLocaleId();
                            if ((localeId == locale) || (localeId.equals(locale))) {
                                if(local.getEnabled()){
                                    logger.info("locale_id:: " + localeId);
                                    logger.info("locale Enabled():: " + local.getEnabled());
                                    List<Section> sections = local.getSections().getSection();
                                    logger.info("sections:: " + sections.size());
                                    httpReq.setAttribute("shfSections", sections);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                isH.close();
                brH.close();
                isF.close();
                brF.close();
                isRH.close();
                brRH.close();
                brRF.close();
                isRF.close();
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("An Exception occured while calling the SHF urls"
                    + exception.getMessage());
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: I see a `catch`,  but not see a `try`, why?

Comment: Added the try as well.

Comment: Added the try as well. I have given the main lines of codes only. There is no problem in the java code compilation or execution.
Problem is URL is keep on changing dynamically. Need a solution for that